# If two linear maps are equal, and one is invertible, does it follow that both are invertible?

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $S,T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ such that $S=T$ and $T$ is invertible.

My intuition says then that $S$ should be invertible as well.

My best guess to show this would be:

> Since $Tv=Sv$, for every $v\in V$, if $Ta=Tb$ then $Sa=Sb$. 
> We know $T$ is injective, so we have $a=b$. 
> Hence $Sa=Sb$ implies $a=b$, and $S$ must be injective. 
> Since $S\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ it follows that $S$ is invertible.

I would love some feedback or thoughts.

Comment: Yes, if two maps are literally equal then they have exactly the same properties, because any argument that establishes a property of one of them is exactly an argument that establishes the same property for the other. Less obvious but still true is that they only have to be *isomorphic* in the sense of being related by a change of coordinates.

Comment: When two mathematical objects $S$ and $T$ are equal then we are talking about one and a single object, say $S$. This $S$ is either "invertible" (whatever that means) or not, and so is $T$, which is $S$ under a certain other denomination.